# Visual Studio schema compare can't find generated script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, schema, sql-server-data-tools, schema-compare

I am performing SQL Server schema comparison using Visual Studio 2017. I am pressing on "Generate script" button of Schema Compare utility and see the message

> "Update scripts generated successfully"

However, I am unable to see the generated script. Any idea where this went or if it failed?

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio Schema Compare tool creates update script in %TEMP% folder. Try to search file with name %TEMP%\LQDB_State_Update1.publish.sql. Number in file name is autoincremented

Comment: Sadly, i had looked there and cannot find anything.

Comment: may be a problem that there is no difference in the schemas and visual studio does not really generate script in this case

Comment: Its showing many differences in the pane. Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: what version of SQL Server Developer Tools do you have? It may be has sense to install the latest version of SSDT from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx) "The generated script appears in a new Transact-SQL Editor window".

When this didn't work for me, i closed all open windows other than the schema compare window and re-checkmarked all differences in the list (i had un-checked some). After doing this and running "Generate Script" again, Visual Studio did actually open a new window with the script (The filename was "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\MyDbName_Update1.publish.sql").

Answer (score 8):

I've noticed that if SSMS is running , SSDT won't generate Schema Compare script. As soon as I close SSMS and try to generate script again SSDT creates one successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct compare from connection string, generate schema file and then compare that file

do this steps:

1. in visual Studio Go To ***Sql Server Object Explorer***
2. Right Click on database name
3. Select ***Extract Data Tier Application***
4. select location for file save
5. select ***Schema Only***
6. deselct all **checkbox option** or check as your compare requirement

do the same for both source database and target database

then

when compare schema select option ***Data-Tier appication file*** option